# Finding a particular permutation

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

**Simple Notation:**

For a permutation $P=(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$ , we define $\{P_k\} = \{a_1,a_2,..,a_k\}$. (i.e. set of first $k$ numbers).

**Problem:**

Given $N=\{1,2,3,..,n\}$ and $m$ subsets of it, $S_1, S_2,..., S_m$. Find a permutation of $N$, called $P$, which satisfies the following condition:

For every $ 1 \leq i \leq m$: $S_i \neq \{P_{|S_i|}\}$.

**Example:**

$N=\{1,2,3\}$
$S_1 = \{1,3\}$
$S_2 = \{1,2\}$
$S_3 = \{3\}$

Answer: P=(2,3,1)

if we change $S_3=\{2,3\}$ there is no such permutation that holds the condition.

Any suggestion or observation about how to construct the permutation efficiently? Or finding a condition for existence of such permutation?

Comment: Simply process the constraints in ascending order of $\#S_j$: first note the constraints on the first element alone, then on the first pair of elements, etc. Each later constraint is a refinement of earlier constraints, so you can just make sure there are possibilities left at each stage.

Comment: @GregMartin So basically what you're saying is checking all n! possible permutations, right?

Comment: No, not really. Take your example. Since $S_3=\{3\}$ is the only singleton set, the permutation $P$ must begin with 1 or 2. That means it must begin with $\{1,2\}$ or $\{1,3\}$, or $\{2,1\}$ or $\{2,3\}$. The first two are ruled out by $S_2$ and $S_1$, so $P$ must begin with $\{2,1\}$ or $\{2,3\}$; that means it must begin with $\{2,1,3\}$ or $\{2,3,1\}$. And we're out of constraints, so those two are valid.